# it's not executing the onCreateViewHolder in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner on Android Studio. I'm doing a project in the University, and we're using Firebase. I'm trying to learn it. So I wanted to make a Search Tool.
I was trying to do this tutorial for Firebase Search: https://youtu.be/b_tz8kbFUsU
Here is the source code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RH9HlhcRsHVkAjHkVoVL3p9aofr9e43C/view

But seems the RecycleView construction is outdated, so I looked for it on the internet how to change it, there are no errors on the compiler but it doesn't show the query list on the RecycleView. So I found on the debugger that it's not executing the onCreateViewHolder.

Main Activity(changed to MainTestActivity):

```
public class MainTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mSearchField;
private ImageButton mSearchBtn;

private RecyclerView mResultList;

private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UsersTest");


    mSearchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);
    mSearchBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search_btn);

    mResultList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.result_list);
    mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String searchText = mSearchField.getText().toString();

            firebaseUserSearch(searchText);

        }
    });
}

private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

    Toast.makeText(MainTestActivity.this, "Started Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

    Log.d(MainTestActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "LOG TEST"/*firebaseSearchQuery.toString()*/);

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<UsersTest> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UsersTest>()
                    .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery, UsersTest.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UsersTest, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_test_layout, parent, false);

            return new UsersViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(UsersViewHolder holder, int position, UsersTest model) {
            // Bind the Users object to the UsersViewHolder
            // ...
        }
        protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, UsersTest model, int position) {


            viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), model.getName(), model.getStatus(), model.getImage());

        }
    };

    mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}


// View Holder Class

public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }

    public void setDetails(Context ctx, String userName, String userStatus, String userImage){

        TextView user_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
        TextView user_status = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        ImageView user_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);


        user_name.setText(userName);
        user_status.setText(userStatus);

        Glide.with(ctx).load(userImage).into(user_image);


    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

tvacstudio is one of the best teachers for Firebase, Unfortunately, some of his firebase videos are outdated; to solve this issues please do this

In your onStart()

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}
```

as well in your onStop():

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

PS: your viewholder should return a view and the bindViewHolder is never used to populate the data that's going to show in your RecyclerView.

Remember that in your viewholder you should pass your layout row (the view where you created the elements that will be seen for the user, like imageviews, textviews and so one) after you put that view inside your viewholder, you need to bind each of those views into your onBindViewHolder in order to populate them with data.

You are passing the viewholder a view here:

```
 View mView;

    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;

    }
```

and retrieving it here:

```
@Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_test_layout, parent, false);

            return new UsersViewHolder(view);
        }
```

This is good and it's ok, but you need to populate the data from list_test_layout in your onbindviewholder, otherwise you will not see results:

```
  @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(UsersViewHolder holder, int position, UsersTest model) {
            // Bind the Users object to the UsersViewHolder
            // ...
        }
```

Please check the official documentation in order to understand better how it works:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

For example, a full complete bindViewHolder and ViewHolder should look like this:

```
@Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(PeopleVH holder, int position, PersonModel model) {
            holder.setPersonFirstName(model.getFirstName()); // we are setting to the holder view the firstname of a user
            holder.setPersonLastName(model.getLastName()); // and we are binding the same data into the lastname
        }

        @Override
        public PeopleVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.single_row_people_rv, parent, false); // here as you can see is the "user_row.xml" that will contain 2 textviews for user name and lastname

            return new PeopleVH(view); // now we return a view in the viewholder in order to access it in the bindviewholder and reference to each of those views to populate
        }
    };
```

Now, applying this to your data it should look like this

```
     @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(UsersViewHolder holder, int position, UsersTest model) {

// just call your UsersTest bean and popualate the data , this is just an example , i dont know what fields you have in UsersTest 

                    holder.setPersonFirstName(model.getFirstName()); // we are setting to the holder view the firstname of a user
                    holder.setPersonLastName(model.getLastName()); // and we are binding the same data into the lastname
                }

                @Override
                public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_test_layout, parent, false); // here as you can see is the "user_row.xml" that will contain 2 textviews for user name and lastname

                    return new UsersViewHolder(view); // now we return a view in the viewholder in order to access it in the bindviewholder and reference to each of those views to populate
                }
            };
```